# Close -> A community-specific reason -> INCONSISTENT

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

If I try to *Close -> A community-specific reason* in the main DIY site, I have an option for *This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network* and then can select Meta DIY.

If I try to *Close -> A community-specific reason* in Meta DIY, I don't have any option for *This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network*.

Why? And can it be fixed?

Somewhat related is the age-old problem of not being able (on the main DIY site) to select a frequently relevant site such as [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) or [Woodworking](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/). But at least we should be able to go from Meta DIY to DIY.

Comment: For the record, I am not aware of any Meta site that has a migration option to the corresponding Main site, where the other way around (main -> meta) is common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the question was previously migrated, and SE has extra steps for mods to migrate a previously migrated question. Unfortunately, those steps are currently broken (500, internal server error, fun times). I've left myself a note to revisit it later to move.